Enumerating AAC audio formats yields incomplete WAVEFORMATEX results
[Note that I use Windows API WAVEFORMATEX structs for legacy reasons. If you don't use WAVEFORMATEX with the Media Foundation lib, you won't have the problem described in this post.]
In order to enumerate available MP3 formats for the builtin codec, I used to call MFTranscodeGetAudioOutputAvailableTypes() and then for each type IMFMediaType::GetRepresentation(AM_MEDIA_TYPE_REPRESENTATION, AM_MEDIA_TYPE ** type_rep). As expected, the type_rep contained the MPEGLAYER3WAVEFORMAT extension of WAVEFORMATEX with the proper size.
void add_mp3_format(std::vector<audio::WaveFormat> & formats, IMFMediaType * const output_type) {
    AM_MEDIA_TYPE * type_rep = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = output_type->GetRepresentation(AM_MEDIA_TYPE_REPRESENTATION, (void **)&type_rep);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        if (type_rep && type_rep->formattype == FORMAT_WaveFormatEx && type_rep->pbFormat && type_rep->cbFormat >= sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX)) {
            WAVEFORMATEX const * const wfx = (WAVEFORMATEX *)type_rep->pbFormat;
            if (wfx->wFormatTag == WAVE_FORMAT_MPEGLAYER3 && wfx->cbSize == MPEGLAYER3_WFX_EXTRA_BYTES) {
                MPEGLAYER3WAVEFORMAT const * const mp3 = (LPMPEGLAYER3WAVEFORMAT)wfx;
                formats.emplace_back(*mp3, L"MP3");
            //} else if (wfx->wFormatTag == WAVE_FORMAT_MPEG_HEAAC && wfx->cbSize >= sizeof(HEAACWAVEINFO) - sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX)) {
            //  HEAACWAVEINFO const * const aac = (LPHEAACWAVEINFO)wfx;
            //  formats.emplace_back(*aac, L"AAC");
            }
        }
        output_type->FreeRepresentation(AM_MEDIA_TYPE_REPRESENTATION, (void *)type_rep);
    }
}

Later, I used these format structs to set the output types for the encoder, using MFInitMediaTypeFromWaveFormatEx() and IMFSinkWriter::AddStream(). This worked fine.
Now I wanted to add AAC formats available with the builtin codec, using the same functions. Unfortunately, that failed because of a bug either in the Media Foundation lib or in the codec itself.
Similar to MPEGLAYER3WAVEFORMAT above, I expected HEAACWAVEINFO or even HEAACWAVEFORMAT structs. But IMFMediaType::GetRepresentation() omits all the special AAC info and returns only the plain old WAVEFORMATEX part. Its cbSize member should be at least 12, but it is 0. Because of that, MFInitMediaTypeFromWaveFormatEx() fails and encoding is not possible. Hoping for the best and stretching the returned structs into HEAACWAVEINFO doesn't help, the required info is indeed missing.
How to get the missing AAC format info and make the encoder work?

IMO you should avoid at all, if you can, using compatibility DirectShow representations. This is half dead code and you hit a bug there, which is possible given the case you described, there is hardly anyone interested in paying any attention to fix this stuff or even investigate. Instead you should rather work with attribute collection directly and marshal it for persistence needs without doing representations.

@RomanRyltsov Yeah, but as I wrote, I'm doing this for legacy reasons. Removing the need for the WAVEFORMATEX representation would require changing a lot of obscure code, way more than what was necessary to implement AAC audio. I also agree that it is unlikely that this bug is ever fixed. That's why I posted the workaround here.

On a related note, I tried modernizing our H264 video encoder code recently. MS recommended in their docu to use IMFAttributes for setting the codec options, because ICodecAPI is deprecated. Turns out that options set through IMFAttributes are ignored, while the ICodecAPI still works, at least that's the case for MS's onboard H264 encoder... So moving to IMFAttributes is not always a good idea.

Another anecdote: The ACM (audio compression manager) API is deprecated too, everyone should use the Media Foundation lib. Turns out that the MP3 codec provided by the MF lib is just a wrapper around the old ACM codec... It looks like this whole system is stitched together from various bits & pieces.

Instead of relying on IMFMediaType::GetRepresentation(AM_MEDIA_TYPE_REPRESENTATION, AM_MEDIA_TYPE ** type_rep), you have to use the IMFAttributes interface of the enumerated IMFMediaType to extract the necessary info manually and then fill a HEAACWAVEINFO with it.
The MF_MT_AAC_* attributes are the missing parts in GetRepresentation(). There should also be a blob field MF_MT_USER_DATA, representing HEAACWAVEFORMAT::pbAudioSpecificConfig or even the whole extra info in HEAACWAVEINFO, but it's not there. Perhaps the blob field MF_MT_MPEG4_SAMPLE_DESCRIPTION should represent HEAACWAVEFORMAT::pbAudioSpecificConfig, but that's unclear. But encoding works even without that part. If you require, there's more info about that last part here.
void add_aac_format(std::vector<audio::WaveFormat> & formats, IMFMediaType * const output_type) {
    UINT32 pt = 0, pli = 0, nc = 0, sps = 0, apbs = 0, ba = 0, bps = 0;
    if (SUCCEEDED(output_type->GetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, &nc)) &&
        SUCCEEDED(output_type->GetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, &sps)) &&
        SUCCEEDED(output_type->GetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_AVG_BYTES_PER_SECOND, &apbs)) &&
        SUCCEEDED(output_type->GetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT, &ba)) &&
        SUCCEEDED(output_type->GetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, &bps)) &&
        SUCCEEDED(output_type->GetUINT32(MF_MT_AAC_PAYLOAD_TYPE, &pt)) &&
        SUCCEEDED(output_type->GetUINT32(MF_MT_AAC_AUDIO_PROFILE_LEVEL_INDICATION, &pli)))
    {
        HEAACWAVEINFO aac_wi {0};
        aac_wi.wfx.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_MPEG_HEAAC;
        aac_wi.wfx.nChannels = nc;
        aac_wi.wfx.nSamplesPerSec = sps;
        aac_wi.wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec = apbs;
        aac_wi.wfx.nBlockAlign = ba;
        aac_wi.wfx.wBitsPerSample = bps;
        aac_wi.wfx.cbSize = sizeof(HEAACWAVEINFO) - sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX);
        aac_wi.wPayloadType = pt;
        aac_wi.wAudioProfileLevelIndication = pli;
        formats.emplace_back(aac_wi, L"AAC");
    }
}

